# Appending two or more zeros in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to add two zeros on a dictionary as values. When i do this the python dictionary returns only a single zero. I don't want to use a list. Why the dictionary behaves like this?

```
dictionary = {}

#new key and values

dictionary['a'] = {0.0,0.0}

#expected result {'a': {0.0,0.0}}

print(dictionary)
```

the console returns this as an output.

```
{'a': {0.0}}
```

Comment: You are putting the zeros in a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which cannot hold duplicates. You must use a `list`, `[0.0, 0.0]` or a tuple `(0.0, 0.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use lists, you can use a tuple, which unlike sets allows duplicates.

```
In [1]: dictionary = {}                                                         

In [2]:  
   ...: dictionary['a'] = (0.0,0.0)                                             

In [3]:  
   ...: print(dictionary)                                                       
{'a': (0.0, 0.0)}
```